QMenu with only one item
I have a menu that has only one item i.e. no sub menu actions
I have tried the following but of course I a get a sub item
m_grabMenu = new QMenu(tr("Grab"));
    m_grabActionMenu = m_menuBar->addMenu(m_grabMenu);
    QAction* grabAction = Mind::Utilities::CreateThemeAction(m_parent, m_menuBar->objectName()
                                                             , "Grab   "
                                                             , "/images/info.png"
                                                             , "tp", false);

    

    m_grabMenu->addAction(grabAction);

    connect(grabAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &Grab::GrabMenu::GrabSL);


I also tried this and it gives me what I need - Almost! - The action text is truncated
    QAction* grabAction = Mind::Utilities::CreateThemeAction(m_parent, m_menuBar->objectName()
                                                             , "Grab   "
                                                             , "/images/info.png"
                                                             , "tp", false);

    m_menuBar->addAction(grabAction);

    connect(grabAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &Grab::GrabMenu::GrabSL);

enter image description here

This question is similar to: How to display icon and text together in PYQT5 menubar. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"I have a menu that has only one item i.e. no sub menu actions" is an inaccurate description: a menu intrinsically contains at least one action, you actually want to just add an action. Your real problem, though, is not that you cannot add that, but that it's not properly displayed. While Qt theoretically supports adding actions (a menu in the menu bar is actually its menuAction()), which can obviously have icons, how they're shown depends on the style, and most of them don't support it. Note that the above suggestion is intended for PyQt, but the problem and solutions apply to C++ as well.
